# Oculus rift facing sky / bed position

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

I'm working for an artists in a unity project where there's different first person POV each POV has different orientations, using OVRManager.display.RecenterPose(); i can achieve the relocation of the right POV, the problem is the installation in the gallery will be in a bed. So i need something to override the horizon position in the OVRCameraRig?

I've seen solutions in other forums that apparently solve this in a way you have to be facing north in the bed position, but i need a solution that is compass independent since the beds are circular and user will be in random orientations when in bed.

Comment: hi Macumbaomuerte - can you tick an answer??

Comment: The only answer posted is not really about the subject im asking, so I cannot tick an answer yet.